# I can't access jenkins remotely

Tags: jenkins, debian

I have installed jenkins on a Debian remote computer but it can't be accessed remotely.

Below is my port when I execute the command `netstat -tulpn` :

```
tcp6   0   0 :::8080        :::*         LISTEN      41417/java
```

Also this what i get when i try to wget on the port :

Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1, 127.0.1.1, ::1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2019-11-12 20:15:45 ERROR 403: Forbidden.

Comment: If you are running with `Docker`, you should specfy `--net host` command

Answer (score 0):

can you access your server, if can, try to change port of the jenkins

Comment: No, I've already tried to change the port to a random one but it responding the same way

Comment: oh yeah, have you set up a firewall on the debian server, you use debian 9?

Comment: i swith of all my firewall service.and also there is my version of debian when i tap the command cat /etc/os-release : cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
VERSION_CODENAME=stretch
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"

Comment: this is what i get when i enter this command to see if ufw is running:
ufw status
Status: inactive

Comment: Jenkins stay cannot access ?

Comment: No I can access now